# Filter an Airtable database for a person with two given family names

Tags: regex, airtable

I'm receiving the values `name` and `surname` captured from a form. Then I'm I'm querying my an Airtable base containing a list of wedding guests using Airtable's airtable.js. The guest list contains a number of guests with double-barreled family names i.e two names split by a hyphen e.g. `name-secondname`. The complication arises when a guest enters only the first part of their family name e.g. `name` which Airtable does not recognise. I thought I would try Airtable's built in REGEX inside a filterByFormula along side `AND` to match `name` and `surname` string up until the hyphen. Something like this:

```
`(AND({name} = "${name}",FIND(REGEX_REPLACE("${surname}",'[^-]*','' ),{surname})>0))`
```

No joy though. Any Ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The answer, almost invariably, will have something to do with `escaped characters`. Try one before the hyphen:

```
`(AND({name} = "${name}",FIND(REGEX_REPLACE("${surname}",'[^\\-]*','' ),{surname})>0))`
```

[Syntax Reference](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax)